# What is current quota left using "useResourceQuotas" & GA 360

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have an application that fetches GA reports with API of users after they give us permission.
Added "useResourceQuotas" and it works fine. I can see quotas left. If a user doesn't use GA 360 there is a message stating the user is not eligible to use this parameter.
Is there a way to determine whether a user has GA 360 before I request a report?
Something from Management API maybe?

Currently I am using an empty report (with only dates) for that, but that looks like an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch Google Analytics [Account Summaries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries#resource) using Management API and check `Web Property Level` in the response i.e. `webProperties[].level`

It can be either `STANDARD` or `PREMIUM` where PREMIUM stands for GA360 web property.